# A partition of my external hard drive doesn't mount on mac

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

My external hard drive has 2 partitions, partition 1 for normal uses and partition 2 for time machine back up.
Both were working fine and I have so many backups in partition 2.
Suddenly my partition 2 won't mount even by forcing it, while the partition 1 is mounted. In Diskutility, I can see the partition 2 as unmounted and nothing works on it (forcing mount, first aid, erase, format,...). For the partition 1, I can see every files in it. However, I can't unmount the partition 1 in this situation.
Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can DiskUtility repair it? If not how about a different disk repair utility like DiskWarrior or others? If those don't work you may be stuck with reformatting the drive (losing everything on it) or sending it off for recovery, which is expen$$ive. That is, assuming it is just a soft error and not a harware error with the drive itself.

Comment: It’s possible the OS is checking the disk before it will mount - use activity monitor and look for fsck running.  Also try `diskutil verifyvolume /Volumes/xxx/` where xxx is the disk name.

Comment: Do you remember what the File System is? Also, does it work on Windows or another Mac?